# modal not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The Modal wont open when i import the Modal with Ajax without ajax the Modal will open without Problems, how i can fix it ?

When i use this Code it will be loaded with a click but it only get Opens with another click how i can make that the useres need only one click to open the Modal ?

Here the Modal code (The Problem):

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#basic-modal a').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content' + this.id).modal({
            overlayClose: true
        });
        return false;
    });

    // Load dialog on page load
    //$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

    // Load dialog on click
    $(document).on('click','#basic-modal', function(){
    $('#basic-modal a').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content' + this.id).modal({
            overlayClose:true
        });
        return false;
    });

    });
});
```

(This is working)
**Modal html:**

```
<div id="basic-modal">
        <a target="_blank" class="textprio2" id="368774" class="basic"> Text
 <span class="fa fa-info"</span></a><br>        
        </div>

        <!-- modal content -->
        <div id=modal-desing >
        <div id="basic-modal-content368774"> Here is the Content
</div></div>
```

(Loaded From DataBase)(Ajax is not the Problem)
**Ajax:**

```
include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
    exit();
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

//fetch records using page position and item per page. 
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT modal FROM animegesamtliste ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?,?");
$i1 = 1;
//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
//for more info https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage
$results->bind_param("dd", $position, $item_per_page); 
$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$results->bind_result($modal); //bind variables to prepared statement

//output results from database
while($results->fetch()){

echo $modal;
}

?>
<script src='_include/js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
```

**Site:**

```
<ul id="results"><!-- results appear here --></ul>

    <div align="center">
        <button id="load_more_button"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"  class="animation_image" style="float:left;"> Load More</button> <!-- load button -->
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var track_page = 1; //track user click as page number, righ now page number 1
load_contents(track_page); //load content

$("#load_more_button").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button
    track_page++; //page number increment everytime user clicks load button
    load_contents(track_page); //load content
});

//Ajax load function
function load_contents(track_page){
    $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

    $.post( 'fetch_pages.php', {'page': track_page}, function(data){

        if(data.trim().length == 0){
            //display text and disable load button if nothing to load
            $("#load_more_button").text("You have reached end of the record!").prop("disabled", true);
        }

        $("#results").append(data); //append data into #results element

        //scroll page to button element
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 800);

        //hide loading image
        $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
    });
```

Comment: No one's going to dig through all these layers of code for you.  You might want to acquaint yourself with the **debugger** in your browser and see what exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: ok now i have make it smaller.

Comment: where is the ajax?

Comment: Afaik there is no modal function in jQuery. A "modal" plugin exists that does that. You are using the plugin? Or you want to make a dialog, with modal attribute?

Comment: i use a jQuery plugin for the modal

Comment: First ajax get called when the page get loaded next when the useres press on the Button load more. My Problem is the Modal code because the useres need too click that the Modals get loaded but not opend at the next click will the script open the Modal but when i remove loaded on click the Modal will not binded on the target.

Answer (score 0):

I get it fixed:

(i change `$(document).on('click','#basic-modal', function(){` to `$(document).on('mouseenter','#basic-modal', function(){`)